# Menu WordPress (SlideToggle)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Адаптивное меню открывается по клику jquery методом SlideToggle. Проблема при переносе меню на WordPress. Если уменьшить ширину браузера до мобильной и открыть меню, а потом увеличить ширину до декстопа, меню не перестраивается аккуратно под декстоп. Это происходит потому, что метод slidetoggle добавляет тегу ul инлайново display: block, когда меню должно перестраиватся под декстоп, этот инлайн стиль не исчезает. К слову на чистой верстки все работает норм, проблемы только с WP меню, делаю его через wp_nav_menu. Как это пофиксить ?(

Comment: Напишите функцию, которая при адаптиве будет проверять раскрыто ли мобильное или нет.

Comment: я к сожалению не настолько еще силен в програмирование, чтобы писать такие функции )

Comment: Добавьте код меню в вопрос (html+css+js)